# Updating state in react async not behaving right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am trying to set up in a `useEffect()` hook subscriptions to an array of firebase documents like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
            const db = firestore();
            const unsubscribeCallbacks: (() => void)[] = [];
            db.collection(CLASS_COLLECTION).doc(id).get().then(doc => {
                const classData = doc.data() as Class;
                for (let student of classData.students) {
                    const unsubscribe = student.onSnapshot(studentSubscribe);
                    unsubscribeCallbacks.push(unsubscribe)
                }
            })
            return () => {
                for (let unsubscribe of unsubscribeCallbacks) {
                    unsubscribe();
                }
            }
        }, [id]
    );
```

`studentSubscribe` is the function where I process the data fetched from the database and update the state:

```
function studentSubscribe(snapshot: DocumentSnapshot) {
        const _students = students;
        const studentData = snapshot.data() as Student;
        //Check if this snapshot is a student update or a new student
        //Also true on the first fetch
        const isStudent = _students.find(val => val.id === studentData.id)
        if (isStudent) {
            console.log("Student updated")
            console.log(studentData)
            _students.map(val => val.id === studentData.id ? studentData : val)
            //Sort alphabetically
            _students.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.name < b.name)
                    return -1;
                else if (a.name === b.name)
                    return 0;
                return 1;
            });
        } else {
            console.log("New student pushed to state")
            console.log(studentData)
            _students.push(studentData);
            //Sort alphabetically
            _students.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.name < b.name)
                    return -1;
                else if (a.name === b.name)
                    return 0;
                return 1;
            });
        }
        console.log("Pushing to state");
        console.log(_students);
        updateStudents(_students);
    }
```

Also `updateStudents` is just a helper function so that I can add some extra logging:

```
function updateStudents(newState:Student[]){
    console.log('Old state')
    console.log(students)
    console.log('New state');
    console.log(newState);
    setStudents(newState);
}
```

The students state is initialized with an empty array. The issue is that after fetching the data from the database and updating the state the state change doesn't get reflected in a rerender. I have logs set up in the components that receive the `student` state as prop. It gets logged when it is an empty array, but not after it gets updated meaning the state update doesn't propagate in props updates.

I also saw some weird behavior in that helper function. The 'old state' log, never logs an empty array as it should on the first call. I never set the state without that function so there should be a call when the state changes from the initial value of an empty array to something else. Instead, the first old state log I get is with the data fetched from the database. All other logs look alright though.

Any idea what is going on wrong here? Thanks in advance!

**Update**:

In `studentSubscribe` changing `const _students = students` to `const _students = [...students]` partially fixed the problem since now the state variable doesn't get messed up.

Now, it seems that in the `students` array, after fetching all the documents from firestore, remains only the data from the last document fetched.

Comment: useEffect has to depend on studentState like [id, students, setStudents]

Comment: this useEffect modifies the `students` state, so passing in `students` as dependency wouldn't just cause an infinite loop?

Comment: you have to fetch data only if "id" is changed

Comment: Whenever the id changes, which is a state property, I need to change the documents I subscribe to

Comment: can you show what you are doing in `setStudents` ?

Comment: setStudents is the state update function returned from 'useState()`

Comment: can you log the `student` state value before and after you call `setStudents` ?

Comment: Yeah, found the issue. When copy the `students` in the local variable `_students`, I assign the array directly instead of copying it with `[...students]`. Now I have another, the `students` array contains the data just from the last document retrieved from firestore. Let me update the post

Comment: Also, logged `students` before and after using `setStudents` inside `updateStudents`, now both logs display an empty array

Comment: checkout this line `setStudents(newState);` , check the value of `newState` to see what is being set.

Comment: I think I found the problem. For a small number of documents, when I try to push them to the state in the initial fetch, they all grab a copy of the empty array and overwrite it, so only the last document to get pushed to the state remains in there. Handling the initial fetched individually fixed that. It's still not working perfect, but I don't know yet if the remaining bugs have anything to do with this thread so I won't mark it as solved yet. Thanks, since logging the state before and after setting it made me realize the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that the initial fetch had to be done in another `useEffect` or the documents would overwrite each other and thus only the last document fetched would remain in the state.  So I changed the code to this

```
//State to mark that all students have been fetched from firestore on mount
const [initialFetchDone, setInitialFetchDone] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
        const db = firestore();
        db.collection(CLASS_COLLECTION).doc(id).get().then(snapshot => {
            const fetchedClass = snapshot.data() as Class;
            setClass(fetchedClass);
            const docs = fetchedClass.students.map(doc => doc.get());
            Promise.all(docs).then(docs => docs.map(doc => doc.data())).then(_students => setStudents(_students as Student[])
            ).then(() => setInitialFetchDone(true))
        })
    }, [id]);

    useEffect(() => {
            const db = firestore();
            const unsubscribeCallbacks: (() => void)[] = [];
            //The initial fetched is handled in the other effect
            if (initialFetchDone) {
                db.collection(CLASS_COLLECTION).doc(id).get().then(doc => {
                    const classData = doc.data() as Class;
                    for (let student of classData.students) {
                        const unsubscribe = student.onSnapshot({includeMetadataChanges:true},studentSubscribe);
                        unsubscribeCallbacks.push(unsubscribe)
                    }
                })
                return () => {
                    for (let unsubscribe of unsubscribeCallbacks) {
                        unsubscribe();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, [id, _class, initialFetchDone]
    );


    function studentSubscribe(snapshot: DocumentSnapshot) {
        const _students = [...students];
        //Ignore local changes
        if (!snapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites) {
            const studentData = snapshot.data() as Student;
            //Check if this snapshot is a student update or a new student
            //Also true on the first fetch
            const isStudent = _students.find(val => val.id === studentData.id)
            if (isStudent) {
                _students.map(val => val.id === studentData.id ? studentData : val)
                //Sort alphabetically
                _students.sort((a, b) => {
                    if (a.name < b.name)
                        return -1;
                    else if (a.name === b.name)
                        return 0;
                    return 1;
                });
            } else {

                _students.push(studentData);
                //Sort alphabetically
                _students.sort((a, b) => {
                    if (a.name < b.name)
                        return -1;
                    else if (a.name === b.name)
                        return 0;
                    return 1;
                });
            }
        }
        setStudents(_students);
    }
```

For my use case I had to ignore local changes so the modifications related local changes and listening to metadata changes aren't related to my initial problem.